# Bash - How to add new line when appending text to a file?

Tags: command-line, bash, git, tee

I'm running this command to append output text data to a markdown file:

```
git log -1 --oneline --skip=1 | tee -a page1.md
```

For the most part functionality is great, but I need to format the output so its readable. Right now, the command above is appending the markdown file like so:

```
Append1 Append2 Append3
```

I need it to be formatted as such:

```
Append1
Append2
Append3
```

With each time the command being run, a new line is created and populated with the `git log` information.

thank you for any guidance on the matter.

Comment: How about `git log -1 --oneline --skip=1 | tee -a page1.md | tr " " "\n"`?

Comment: Why not use bash output redirection like `git log -1 --oneline --skip=1 >> page1.md`?

Comment: These examples work, but not the way you would expect to a markdown file.

Comment: @ArRakin Does your command append \n at the end of the git log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hannu's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1412803/566421) looks correct, but if you want to perform it as single line command - one of the possible ways is to use the `cat` command and [process substitution](https://linuxhandbook.com/bash-process-substitution/) like this:

```bash
cat <(git log -1 --oneline --skip=1) <(echo) | tee -a page1.md
```

It looks like you are using this frequently so you can add the following function at the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file:

```bash
function git-log-1 () { cat <(git log -1 --oneline --skip=1) <(echo) | tee -a "$1"
```

Then do `source ~/.bashrc` or open a new terminal and use the function as shell command:

```bash
git-log-1 page1.md
```

Answer (score 2):

```
git log -1 --oneline --skip=1 | tee -a page1.md
echo >> page1.md
```

The `echo` will append a single newline.
*I'm assuming `--oneline` does indeed add a single line for each invocation.*

---

*Alternative, single line:*

```
git log -1 --oneline --skip=1 | tee -a page1.md && echo >> page1.md
```